# Microsoft Academic--how to search for a paper by DOI?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I can get good results with evaluate queries on titles and author names (and interpret queries).

But what if I want to look up a paper by DOI?

I can get the DOI information of an entry by the extended metadata description (in the attributes of an existing search), but since the extended metadata is a JSON-encoded string which only supports matching, I can't work out how to use the expr field to query by DOI and get a specific paper.

Answer (score 0):

As DOI is not an indexed (separate) attribute, you can not searched publication by DOI now. We decided to add DOI attribute to schema, so you will be able to execute a query like /evaluate?expr=DOI='10.1159/000312628' soon.

Comment: orientatively when it will be available? I also found useful searching by doi.

Comment: has there been any advance on this?

Comment: @DmitryBimatov-MSFT any progress on the DOI based query?

Answer (score 0):

You can query with DOI now. However you have use capital letters for the DOI value as suggested in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-query-expression-syntax. For example, if it is 10.1016/j.stem.2015.01.015, query according to this DOI=='10.1016/J.STEM.2015.01.015'